# “TF14045: The identity <guid> is not a Recognized identity” with TFS 2012 update 4 after upgrade from 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

We recently migrated from TFS 2005 to TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 (Update 4)

TFS 2005 to TFS 2010 was done through a upgrade process.  TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 was done through a detach (from TFS2010 box) and re-attach method (on TFS 2012 box)

One of our users is getting the following error.

“TF14045: The identity  is not a Recognized identity”

The problem seems to be related to his machine name & workspace.

When I try to search TFS workspaces by computer name using Team Foundation Sidekicks 2012, I get the same error.

If the person works from a different pc, he doesn't have any issue.

Here is some stuff that I've tried

- I tried deleting his profile and that didn't work.
- Tried installing vs2013 to see if it's a Visual studio 2010 issue and that didn't work
- Reinstalled the pc but with the same name and I'm still getting the error.
- Tried to change the pc name, take it out of the domain, re-connect to the domain but that didn't work

I haven't tried to rebuild the machine again but with a different name to see what happens. I just want to see if anyone has any suggestions before I redo that long task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I rebuilt the pc with a brand new name.  After that the user had no more issues logging in.

I still get the error when I search TFS by machine name in Team Foundation Sidekicks but I think an answer to that is a lost cause.

**

update - After 2 years, I decided to go clean up old workspaces in TFS.
I noticed that still having the reported issue when trying view all my workspaces on a specific collection.

(tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /collection:....)

I opened up an incident ticket with Microsoft.

The answer, after a bit of troubleshooting, was to clear out the bad  from the collection table - tbl_VCIdentityMap

Once we cleared out the first entry, i would retry the tf workspaces command and a new guid error would pop up.

I ended up clearing 25 entries from that table and then the issue with tf workspaces went away.

The guid that would pop up in the error message equals the TeamFoundationServerId located in many of the collection tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PowerShell wrapper that I used to delete all workspaces for a given user:

```
Set-Alias -Name 'tf' -Value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe' # amend path so it points to your tf.exe file

# fetch a list of all workspaces and store them in an xml variable
$x = [xml](tf workspaces /computer:* /owner:* /format:xml)

# determine who we want to delete (this is used in our filter later; to delete all, just skip the filter
$userToDelete = 'Someone@example.com'

# for each workspace 
# take those where the owner's display name matches our target user
# then delete that workspace (I've left prompts enabled, so you can manually validate things; add /noprompt to avoid that
$x.Workspaces.Workspace | ?{$_.ownerdisp -eq $userToDelete} | %{tf vc workspace /delete "$($_.name);$($_.owner)"}
```

More info on available options in the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=azure-devops); so you can tweak the above per your exact requirements.

Thanks to [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/267507/cant-delete-an-abandoned-vsts-workspace.html) for showing me the XML output trick.

Answer (score 0):

In our scenario, we were in the middle of a TFS to Azure DevOps Server migration.

Received the same error when connecting Visual Studio 2019 back to to TFS repos after being connected to new Azure DevOps instance.

Deleting the workspaces manually via Source Control Explorer did the trick.

Answer (score -2):

I've done OK: I rename/remove Workspace that connect error from TFS_Database.dbo.tbl_Workspace