# Can't get all labels inside TFS

Tags: tfs, corruption

When I try to run the command

```
TF labels /owner:*
```

I get the error

```
Data is Null.  This method or property cannot be called on Null Values.
```

At this point, I'm assuming that it's a database corruption similar to what I've experienced in the past - [“TF14045: The identity <guid> is not a Recognized identity” with TFS 2012 update 4 after upgrade from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548249/tf14045-the-identity-guid-is-not-a-recognized-identity-with-tfs-2012-update/20660620#20660620)

I can get labels from other collection and get labels from specific users.

I'm going open up an incident ticket but I wanted to check here to see if anyone had a potential solution.

Cheers

Comment: Did you just mean only encountered the `TF labels /owner:*` occurs error

Comment: problemCould you see result through Source Control Explorer window, right-click the sub-folder for which you want to list the relevant labels and pick View History from the context menu and then select labels?

Comment: Hey Patrick, yes the problem only occurs when I run "tf labels /owner:*"  If I put my name as the owner, I see all my labels, If I change collection and do /owner:*, it all works.  We've had issues with bad users in the database before.  I've placed an incident ticket with Microsoft and i'll report back with an answer when everything is fixed.

Comment: it's hard to pinpoint which label is the issue as wel have about 50 projects in the collection and i'm not sure what user is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue was in the end that TFS labels were associated to user accounts that didn't exist anymore.

The microsoft rep created the following script below.  It assigns the bad labels to an existing account.

```
/* Script to reassign TFVC artifact ownership to an existing identity
 * The 16 was selected from the healthy identities as 
 * determined by this script 
   SELECT  *
   FROM    tbl_VCIdentityMap vcim
   LEFT JOIN tbl_Identity i
   ON      i.PartitionId = vcim.PartitionId
           AND i.Id = vcim.TeamFoundationId
   WHERE   i.PartitionId IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY IdentityId
 */

DECLARE @ownerId INT = 844

-- tbl_Labels
UPDATE  l
SET     l.OwnerId = @ownerId
FROM    tbl_Label l
LEFT JOIN tbl_VCIdentityMap vcim
ON      vcim.PartitionId = l.PartitionId
        AND vcim.IdentityId = l.OwnerId
WHERE   l.PartitionId = 1
        AND vcim.IdentityId IS NULL

-- tbl_Workspace
UPDATE  w
SET     w.OwnerId = @ownerId
FROM    tbl_Workspace w
LEFT JOIN tbl_VCIdentityMap vcim
ON      vcim.PartitionId = w.PartitionId
        AND vcim.IdentityId = w.OwnerId
WHERE   w.PartitionId = 1
        AND vcim.IdentityId IS NULL

-- tbl_Branch
UPDATE  b
SET     b.OwnerId = @ownerId
FROM    tbl_Branch b
LEFT JOIN tbl_VCIdentityMap vcim
ON      vcim.PartitionId = b.PartitionId
        AND vcim.IdentityId = b.OwnerId
WHERE   b.PartitionId = 1
        AND vcim.IdentityId IS NULL

-- tbl_Changeset OwnerId
UPDATE  c
SET     c.OwnerId = @ownerId
FROM    tbl_Changeset c
LEFT JOIN tbl_VCIdentityMap vcim
ON      vcim.PartitionId = c.PartitionId
        AND vcim.IdentityId = c.OwnerId
WHERE   c.PartitionId = 1
        AND vcim.IdentityId IS NULL

-- tbl_Changeset CommitterId
UPDATE  c
SET     c.CommitterId = @ownerId
FROM    tbl_Changeset c
LEFT JOIN tbl_VCIdentityMap vcim
ON      vcim.PartitionId = c.PartitionId
        AND vcim.IdentityId = c.CommitterId
WHERE   c.PartitionId = 1
        AND vcim.IdentityId IS NULL
```

After this script, I was able to run the labels command.  But there were still some bad accounts - TF14132: Identity not found

With the names of the labels, I was able to get the identity of the bad user and update them with a good user.

```
select * from tbl_Label where LabelName like '%BadLabelIdentityName%'

DECLARE @ownerId INT = GoodIdentityNumber
UPDATE  l
SET     l.OwnerId = @ownerId
FROM    tbl_Label l
where l.OwnerId = BadIdentityNumber
```